# Limit number of instances of a *standard* azure webjob when scaling out

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Very similar to (but not a duplicate of!) this question: [Limit number of instances of an azure webjob when scaling out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067648/limit-number-of-instances-of-an-azure-webjob-when-scaling-out)

I would like to be able to limit the number of instances of a webjob within our **standard** webapp. I am aware of the possibility of having a [*singleton* instance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2014/05/19/how-to-run-a-continuous-webjob-as-a-singleton/) but would like to be able to limit this to a number other than 1.

Is such a thing possible? If not, are there any sensbile workarounds for the type of scenario described in [q. 45067648](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067648/limit-number-of-instances-of-an-azure-webjob-when-scaling-out) for those of us running on the Standard App Service?

---

*Footnote on why this isn't a duplicate of [q. 45067648](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067648/limit-number-of-instances-of-an-azure-webjob-when-scaling-out):*

*I asked the previous question without considering that there could be a different answer depending on whether the app service was running on a premium or standard SKU. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45069574/2455494) Amor gave would be an ideal answer for those running on the premium SKU but is unsuitable for those running the standard SKU. I considered amending the original question but, after advice on meta ([here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352334/correct-action-if-you-need-to-change-or-clarify-a-question-as-a-result-of-an-ans) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254521/editing-question-for-new-answer)), discovered this is best posed as a new question*

Answer (score 1):

> limit the number of instances of a webjob within our standard webapp.

Under "[Create a continuously running WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs#a-namecreatecontinuousacreate-a-continuously-running-webjob)" section in the article, you can see: ***"If your web app runs on more than one instance, a continuously running WebJob will run on all of your instances"***. And it enables us to make [continuous WebJob to run on only one instance](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2014/05/19/how-to-run-a-continuous-webjob-as-a-singleton/).

To limit the number of instances that continuous WebJob run on, **Amor** has gave you a workaround in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067648/limit-number-of-instances-of-an-azure-webjob-when-scaling-out): using [Per app scaling feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-high-density-hosting#per-app-scaling) (available only for Premium SKU App Service plans). If you do not want to scale your **Standard** SKU App Service plan to **Premium** SKU App Service plan, you can create another new **Standard** SKU App Service plan with specific number of instance that you want to run your WebJob, in this way, your WebJob will not cause resource contention with other web apps.

Besides, you can give a feedback on [Azure UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).